# Changing Template

Tags: wpf, templates

I have a togglebutton on which I want to use two different template on Checked and Unchecked State.

When the ToggleButton is Clicked (IsChecked=True) I want to Use template 1 and when it is clicked for the second time I want to use Template 2.

That's it !!!

How can I do that ?? Should I use Event Trigger or Trigger for that ???

Answer (score 1):

You can change the Template's on an element by assigning them through a style, instead of directly to the element.  In our style we can assign a trigger that is fired when the IsChecked property of the ToggleButton is set to True/False, and then within that trigger we can change the assigned template.  A sample Style for our ToggleButton would look like this:

```
<ToggleButton Content="Toggle Me">
    <ToggleButton.Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
            <Setter Property="Template"
                    Value="{StaticResource ToggleButtonUncheckedTemplate}" />
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsChecked"
                         Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Template"
                            Value="{StaticResource ToggleButtonCheckedTemplate}" />
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </ToggleButton.Style>
</ToggleButton>
```

The two StaticResource's are our predefined ControlTemplates.  While this works, I would recomend to just make the modifications needed inside the Template, instead of completely swapping the ControlTemplate for another one.

Just like we did in the style, we could create a Trigger inside the ControlTemplate that changes what is needed:

```
        <ControlTemplate x:Key="ToggleButtonUncheckedTemplate"
                         TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
            <Grid SnapsToDevicePixels="False"
                  Background="Transparent">
                ... layout ...
            </Grid>

            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsChecked"
                         Value="true">
                    <Setter Property="Data"
                            TargetName="arrow"
                            Value="M 1,4  L 4,1  L 7,4" />
                </Trigger>
                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver"
                         Value="true">
                    <Setter Property="Stroke"
                            TargetName="circle"
                            Value="#666" />
                    <Setter Property="Stroke"
                            TargetName="arrow"
                            Value="#222" />
                    <Setter Property="Visibility"
                            TargetName="shadow"
                            Value="Visible" />
                </Trigger>
            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>

        </ControlTemplate>
```